# concat with left in sql

Tags: sql, concatenation

i have two columens in the same table:

```
Column A :abcdef
Column B :12345
```

I want Column A value to be replaced by :

```
abcdef123
```

therefore i want all the data from column A plus the 3 first digit from column B.

I am stuck big time. I use Microsft SQL server Mgt Studio.

any help is welcome.

thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: thank you so much, worked a treat. my 42949 rows are now updated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as simple as this:

```
update table set ColumnA = ColumnA + LEFT(ColumnB, 3)
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
set ColumnA=(select CONCAT(ColumnA,LEFT(ColumnB,3)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use LEFT string function :

DECLARE @colA VARCHAR(100) = 'abcdef'
DECLARE @colB VARCHAR(100) = '12345'

SELECT @colA + LEFT(@colB,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Update Table_name SET ColumnA = ColumnA+LEFT(ColumnB,3)
```

Comment: Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since another user already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up instead of repeating the same information.